# $X^{\ast}$ reflexive but not $X$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ a normed vector space that is not Banach. It is true that if $X$ is reflexive, then $X^{\ast}$ is reflexive. But what about the converse?

If $X$ was a Banach space then it will follow, but if it is not the case, is there any example?

Comment: As the dual of a normed space in Banach, then surely any reflexive normed space is Banach (as it's $X^{**}$).

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, I don't see how this is related with what I asked.

Comment: @LeonardoCavenaghi I believe that Lord Shark the Unknown means that every reflexive normed space must be Banach: $X''$ is complete (this basically follows from the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), hence $\iota(X)=X''$, where $\iota$ denotes the canonical embedding $X\to X''$. Since $\iota$ is isometric, we can conclude that $X$ is complete. So if $X$ is not Banach, then it can't be reflexive.

Comment: thank you @haemi, this solved the problem

Comment: @LeonardoCavenaghi glad to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reflexive space is complete. Take a dense, proper (hence incomplete) subspace $X$ of a reflexive space $Y$. Then $X^*\cong Y^*$ is reflexive but $X$ is not.

Comment: For completeness (no pun intended), one should also note the following: if $X$ is complete and $X^*$ is reflexive, then $X$ is reflexive (indeed, $X$ is isomorph to a closed subspace of the reflexive space $X^{**}$).

Comment: Why is $X^{\ast} \cong Y^{\ast}$ ?

Comment: @AdithyaS, continuous linear functionals are uniformly continuous (even Lipschitz) so they uniformly extend to the completion/closure.